# How do national teams get status to play in test cricket by ICC?

Tags: rules, cricket, icc

The all teams playing in ODI & T20 cricket are not able to play test cricket.
so, which conditions as per ICC norms are to be fulfilled by national team/board to get the status of test playing nation?

Answer (score 3):

There's no fixed standard; it's a matter of showing over a number of years that the team would have the ability to be competitive at the very top level of cricket.

Answer (score 0):

Test matches are the highest level of cricket although, statistically, their data forms part of first-class cricket. Matches are played between national representative teams with "Test status", as determined by the International Cricket Council. As of December 2014, ten national teams have Test status, the most recently promoted being Bangladesh in 2000. Zimbabwe's Test status was voluntarily suspended, because of poor performances between 2006 and 2011; it returned to competition in August 2011.[9 countries]

In January 2014, during the historic ICC meeting in Dubai, the pathway for new potential test nations was laid out with the winners of the next round of the ICC Intercontinental Cup playing a 5-day match against the bottom rank test nation. If the Associate team defeats the test nation, then they could be added as the new test country and be given full membership.

Ireland playing cricket since 1993 including 3 World cup appearance but still they have no official test status.In 2009, Ireland stated its intention to apply for Full Membership of the ICC with the aim of achieving Test status,[11th country] and restated its intention in 2012, but the 2012 plan aims to achieve Test status by 2020.

Getting test status loyalty to any bottom rank cricket nations is like winning a  Jackpot. But there cricket board should involve more international cricket and they prove there winning strategy to ICC to get a Test status and also its a pains takingly long process for lower ranking nations.

In 2014, the ICC announced the introduction of the ICC Test Challenge, which will see the holder of the Intercontinental Cup play a pair of two five-day match series against the lowest ranked test-playing nation every four years, starting in 2018